# Dynamically Getting Property Value From Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which i want to retrieve a property from it dynamically

here is a sample from the class

```
namespace TEST
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i am trying to use GetProperty but it always return null

```
static object PropertyGet(object p, string propName)
{
    Type t = p.GetType();
    PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);
    if (info == null)
        return null;
    return info.GetValue(propName);
}
```

like this

```
    var data = new Data();

    var x = PropertyGet(data, "Username");
    Console.Write(x?? "NULL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong, and should be throwing an exception for you:

```
return info.GetValue(propName);
```

You need to pass in the object from which to extract the property, i.e.

```
return info.GetValue(p);
```

Also note that currently `data.Username` *is* null. You want something like:

```
var data = new Data { Username = "Fred" };
```

I've validated that with these two changes, it works.

Comment: i tried it but still i have NULL, also if i passed p which is the class how could i specify which property i need ?!!

Comment: ok ok it is working with string but what if i have OrderedDictionary and want to get somevalues from it ?

Comment: @DanialEugen: You've already done that, because `info` is the `PropertyInfo`. You really *won't* get a null value if your object has a non-null value for that property.

Comment: @DanialEugen: Then you fetch the property value (the `OrderedDictionary`) as before, cast to the right type and then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static object PropertyGet(object p, string propName)
    {
        Type t = p.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);

        if (info == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return info.GetValue(p, null);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data() { Username = "Fred" };

        var x = PropertyGet(data, "Username");
        Console.Write(x ?? "NULL");
    }
}
```